StringApp Fails to install
StringApp fails to install in Cytoscape 3.9.1 and RCy3 commands to upload list of STRING identifiers to Cytoscape do not work. Error states namespace is not available and if I view the default port http://127.0.0.1:1234/v1/commands/ String is not listed amongst the namespace options. I have tried updating Cytoscape but when but when I download the dmg installer it has a No Entry sign across the icon. I'm on an Intel MacBook Pro, 2018 running MacOS 14.5 with Java 8 update 421.

The string namespace will definitely not be there if StringApp is not installed.  Can you give us a bit more information about what happens when you try to install StringApp?  You'll definitely need to use an older version since 3.9 was Java 11 I think and everything is now Java 17.  I assume you downloaded the Mac OS Intel installer when you tried to do an update?
